# Facebook Like and/or Subscribe from WP7

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-like, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm working on a native WP7.1 app.
One requirements is to give the user the possiblity to perform a Facebook Like or Subscribe operation from within the app.

For example I show a post (not through the browser ma in xaml) and I would like to add a like button that make the user like that post on facebook (previous authentication of course).
The same for Subscribe, Post and Share functionalities.

I'm trying to dig into Facebook C# SDK but I haven't found any documentation.

Do you know if it is possible and how ?

Regards
Luca

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ShareLinkTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394009%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

If it's not exactly what you want (display the Facebook button), maybe you can add a WebBrowser control and display the HTML code of the button in it. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikeormond/archive/2010/12/16/displaying-html-content-in-windows-phone-7.aspx

I'm not sure that's possible because I don't know if the Facebook session is shared with webbrowser controls (outside the IE application)

Answer (score 0):

Share/Post : 2 possibilities :

- using an Facebook account on WP7 and using a ShareStatusTask only for FB

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394027%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

- After authentification using a WebBrowser control you need to use a WebRequest (WebRequest.Method = "POST";) with the message.

You can choose a special wall to post your message using code like this : 
WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/" + ID of the Wall + "/feed");